# Using gsub to replace \ to create an URL string

Tags: r

I am using gsub to replace \, but I receive an error. I have already tried with

First idea (Wrong!)

```
root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json\""
u <- gsub("\", "", u)
```

Second idea (Wrong!)

```
root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json\""
u <- gsub("[\]", "", u)
```

Any other idea?

I am using the root variable for this:

```
 parameters <- "&key=my-key"
 root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json\""
 apiRequests <- paste(root, "?address=", "paris, france", 
 "\"",parameters,sep = "")

 conn <- httr::GET(URLencode(apiRequests))
 apiResponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(conn, "text"))
```

Comment: As you have written it above, `root` ends in a double quote `\"`.  Is this a typo or did you intend this?

Comment: I don't think that it's there in the first place, try doing `cat("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json\"")` and you will see it in the output.

Comment: The \ is a special character used in regex expressions, to replace it try escaping it with \.  So try using “\\”

Comment: Is that slash supposed to be escaping the quote or something?  What is `u`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually I was intended to eliminate it.

Comment: @Elin The slash is something that I tried to delete.

Comment: Yes but I was asking how it got into the string.

Comment: @Elin Well, I added the backslash when I tried to include double quotes at the end of the string   `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json`. Now, think about that again, it sounds like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this

```
root <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json\""
root <- gsub('\"', "", root)
```

The back slash is escaping the first `"`     and so then you want to replace the escaped `"`  which is `\"`   and use single quotes to keep the quoting straight.